# How to handle credit card validation in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

During my jmeter script recording I am getting following error

```
 Please provide valid credit card information
```

But when I use the same data to manually execute the flow from browser,there is no issues.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because Jmeter certificate was not installed on the browser.